# how oil molded fan ( Deep cool Alta 7)

Tags: fan

i have a deep cool alta 7 cpu heat sink and fan. fan is slow uped. how can i oil it fan. fan is molded. above of fan is a metal piece that is not removeable.
is tehre any way to fix fan?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Don't oil any sealed bearing device.

1. it won't help &
2. it could dribble into more important things.

If cleaning does not free it up, discard it & buy a new one. They cost about $£€ 1.

To clean properly, you need to remove the fan assembly from the heat sink [it should just pull off at the 4 lugs you can see on the join, it doesn't even need you to remove the heat sink from the CPU], then the fan from the motor axle - you can do that by simply pulling vertically ["down", in its current orientation] away from the motor, but sometimes there is so much resistance you will break it anyway, so it's not usually worth the effort.
Try a good squirt of contact cleaner instead.

Comment: thanks bro but all things in iran are expensive. thanks to trump sanctions and our government help trump plan.

Comment: I'm not sure what politics has to do with it - you can buy one of these fans for next to nothing on eBay. Give or take a bit of fancy shaping to look 'cool' they're all the same, completely interchangeable. They're not fixable, they have sealed bearings. I've set out your options in the answer.